# how to write app that will make a NEW html page and fill it by copying the information from other website?

Tags: html

i need for my website www.livegol.co.il some app that will make the pages automatically and fill some information inside the page by copying it from other website.
**for EX:**
the app will be make automatically the homepage on 10:00 AM everyday, by copying the name of the teams that are playing from here: www.livescore.com

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you'll probably want some php scraper type tool which is triggered by a cron job at the specified time.

there are plenty of website scraper scripts out there. i recently used one for some IMDB content.

hope this helps